# Casbah MongoDB Error

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I have the Casbah MongoDB driver that I use in my Web Application and when I tried to connect to the Database which is when the Casbah driver API's are called, I face a strange error:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.mongodb.casbah.Imports$ does not implement the requested interface com.mongodb.casbah.query.dsl.SearchOp]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:165) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:162) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:185) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:387) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:387) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$$anon$1.execute(Execution.scala:43) [com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:37) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:133) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:58) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Future.scala:278) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Future.scala:278) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(Future.scala:731) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Future.scala:746) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Future.scala:723) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Future.scala:723) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch.run(Future.scala:722) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.scala$concurrent$Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$$unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:782) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:773) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:37) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:133) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:58) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:274) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:274) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$$anon$2.execute(Execution.scala:70) [com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:37) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:133) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:58) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.mongodb.casbah.Imports$ does not implement the requested interface com.mongodb.casbah.query.dsl.SearchOp
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:314) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:108) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:107) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:107) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:100) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:481) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:481) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:517) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:517) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:493) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:493) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.mongodb.casbah.Imports$ does not implement the requested interface com.mongodb.casbah.query.dsl.SearchOp
    at com.mongodb.casbah.query.dsl.SearchOp$class.$init$(BarewordOperators.scala:405) ~[casbah-query_2.10-2.7.0-RC2.jar:2.6.2]
    at com.mongodb.casbah.Imports$.<init>(Implicits.scala:142) ~[casbah-core_2.10-2.7.0-RC2.jar:2.7.0-RC2]
    at com.mongodb.casbah.Imports$.<clinit>(Implicits.scala) ~[casbah-core_2.10-2.7.0-RC2.jar:2.7.0-RC2]
    at com.q31.scerticles.core.domain.content.Exam$.getAllExamsForTechnologyWithPagination(Exam.scala:59) ~[scerticles-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.q31.scerticles.core.service.ContentService.allExamsForTechnologyWithPagination(ContentService.scala:46) ~[scerticles-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at controllers.content.ExamController$$anonfun$allExamsForTechnology$1.apply(ExamController.scala:37) ~[com-q31-scerticles.com-q31-scerticles-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at controllers.content.ExamController$$anonfun$allExamsForTechnology$1.apply(ExamController.scala:35) ~[com-q31-scerticles.com-q31-scerticles-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Action.scala:221) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Action.scala:220) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:357) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:309) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Looks like there seems to be some sort of library incompatibility, but just don't know which one. Any clues? Here are my libraries so far!

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     4467 Jun 14 09:09 aopalliance-1.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   167386 Jun 14 09:09 casbah-commons_2.10-2.7.0-RC2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   286110 Jun 14 09:09 casbah-core_2.10-2.7.0-RC2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    79191 Jun 14 09:09 casbah-gridfs_2.10-2.7.0-RC2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   223987 Jun 14 09:09 casbah-query_2.10-2.7.0-RC2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   264600 Jun 14 09:09 ch.qos.logback.logback-classic-1.0.13.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   418870 Jun 14 09:09 ch.qos.logback.logback-core-1.0.13.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    33491 Jun 14 09:09 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   191738 Jun 14 09:09 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   866104 Jun 14 09:09 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   117309 Jun 14 09:09 com.github.nscala-time.nscala-time_2.10-0.2.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1295513 Jun 14 09:09 com.github.scala-incubator.io.scala-io-core_2.10-0.4.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   437576 Jun 14 09:09 com.github.scala-incubator.io.scala-io-file_2.10-0.4.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2189117 Jun 14 09:09 com.google.guava.guava-14.0.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1549098 Jun 14 09:09 com.h2database.h2-1.3.172.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   110600 Jun 14 09:09 com.jolbox.bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    75459 Jun 14 09:09 com.jsuereth.scala-arm_2.10-1.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    46725 Jun 14 09:09 commons-codec.commons-codec-1.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    60686 Jun 14 09:09 commons-logging.commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   500511 Jun 14 09:09 com.ning.async-http-client-1.7.18.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    30190 Jun 14 09:09 com.thoughtworks.paranamer.paranamer-2.5.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2643414 Jun 14 09:09 com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    14477 Jun 14 09:09 com.typesafe.akka.akka-slf4j_2.10-2.2.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   187497 Jun 14 09:09 com.typesafe.config-1.0.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     7012 Jun 14 09:09 com.typesafe.netty.netty-http-pipelining-1.1.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   294444 Jun 14 09:09 com.typesafe.play.anorm_2.10-2.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3774943 Jun 14 09:09 com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    35156 Jun 14 09:09 com.typesafe.play.play-cache_2.10-2.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     5198 Jun 14 09:09 com.typesafe.play.play-datacommons_2.10-2.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     4571 Jun 14 09:09 com.typesafe.play.play-exceptions-2.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   366840 Jun 14 09:09 com.typesafe.play.play-functional_2.10-2.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   716463 Jun 14 09:09 com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.10-2.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   201709 Jun 14 09:09 com.typesafe.play.play-jdbc_2.10-2.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   627243 Jun 14 09:09 com.typesafe.play.play-json_2.10-2.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     8759 Jun 14 09:09 com.typesafe.play.sbt-link-2.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    39142 Jun 14 09:09 com.typesafe.play.templates_2.10-2.2.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   187497 Jun 14 09:09 config-1.0.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   710492 Jun 14 09:09 guice-3.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1208356 Jun 14 09:09 io.netty.netty-3.7.0.Final.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     2497 Jun 14 09:09 javax.inject-1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    15071 Jun 14 09:09 javax.transaction.jta-1.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    40544 Jun 14 09:09 joda-convert-1.3.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   581571 Jun 14 09:09 joda-time-2.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   581571 Jun 14 09:09 joda-time.joda-time-2.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   586498 Jun 14 09:09 mongo-java-driver-2.12.0-rc2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1346296 Jun 14 09:09 net.sf.ehcache.ehcache-core-2.6.6.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   183875 Jun 14 09:09 nscala-time_2.10-0.6.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     6512 Jun 14 09:09 oauth.signpost.signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    45277 Jun 14 09:09 oauth.signpost.signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   315805 Jun 14 09:09 org.apache.commons.commons-lang3-3.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   291037 Jun 14 09:09 org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient-4.0.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   172888 Jun 14 09:09 org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore-4.0.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   713930 Jun 14 09:09 org.javassist.javassist-3.18.0-GA.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    40544 Jun 14 09:09 org.joda.joda-convert-1.3.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    86503 Jun 14 09:09 org.json4s.json4s-ast_2.10-3.1.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   462450 Jun 14 09:09 org.json4s.json4s-core_2.10-3.1.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    63432 Jun 14 09:09 org.json4s.json4s-native_2.10-3.1.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14411577 Jun 14 09:09 org.scala-lang.scala-compiler-2.10.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7121818 Jun 14 09:09 org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   854338 Jun 14 09:09 org.scala-lang.scalap-2.10.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3171168 Jun 14 09:09 org.scala-lang.scala-reflect-2.10.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   650514 Jun 14 09:09 org.scala-stm.scala-stm_2.10-0.7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    16517 Jun 14 09:09 org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     4960 Jun 14 09:09 org.slf4j.jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    26084 Jun 14 09:09 org.slf4j.slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7126003 Jun 14 09:09 scala-library-2.10.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3171168 Jun 14 09:09 scala-reflect-2.10.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7195811 Jun 14 09:09 scalatest_2.10-2.1.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    26084 Jun 14 09:09 slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   201315 Jun 14 09:09 tyrex.tyrex-1.0.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1367760 Jun 14 09:09 xerces.xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   220536 Jun 14 09:09 xml-apis.xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
```

Comment: Could you try using Casbah 2.7.2 which is the latest? And see if you get any errors.  Also any code reproducing the issue would help if upgrading doesn't fix it.

Comment: I can definitely try that and post my findings, but this is really strange as it did not complain for a couple of builds and all of a sudden it started to fail for no reason or what-so-ever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `casbah 2.8.1` version which could solve your problem.